# how to increase the limit of exceptions in oracle SQLLDR

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-loader

how to increase the limit of exceptions in oracle ?

i have a excel sheet in which their are about 900 records to be appended .so i converted the excel to dat file and wrote a batch file that read from the dat file and appends it to the concern table  but the batch file stop  execution once the exceptions reach 51(all integrity constrain   parent key not found) so the remaining valid files are not updated .its very difficult to find which record has integrity constrain is there a way to increase this exception limit ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the [ERRORS](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_params.htm#sthref573) SQLLDR command line parameter.